# Nothing show up when opening old project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I can't see basic windows like activity_main.xml, mainActivity.kt, when I open old projects. Please refer to the screenshot. Please advise me on how to set them up to be shown automatically as normal when I open old projects.

**no activity_main.xml**
[image: no activity_main.xml]

The below image is normal to view.

**normal view**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the Tab "Project" that is in the upper left corner to view all the files of that particular project.

Refer to a Youtube tutorial to get comfortable with Android Studio IDE.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I want to set them up showing automatically when I open the project.